# Change Color of Background in javaFX Canvas

Tags: canvas, javafx-2, javafx-8

How do we change the background of JavaFX canvas?
The only solution I have now is:

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

Is there another solution except drawing a rectangle? I searched in CSS but canvas doesn't have `-fx-background-color`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The canvas is essentially "blank" (i.e. transparent) unless you draw onto it. You can create the effect of a background by placing it into a layout pane and setting the background of the layout pane:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CanvasBackground extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        StackPane holder = new StackPane();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400,  300);

        holder.getChildren().add(canvas);
        root.getChildren().add(holder);

        holder.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```